# How do I add a different Button to my generated GridView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, adapter

I created a layout with a GridView Adapter which looks like this: https://gyazo.com/20990f2640d115e8751c386f51913142
How can I add a button like this, that it is scrollable too?:
https://gyazo.com/46806b05c52e963f146cc7f87f2017b1

My Adapter in a Fragment:

```
package com.aaron.waller.tanzverbotsoundboard.mFragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.aaron.waller.tanzverbotsoundboard.MainActivity;
import com.aaron.waller.tanzverbotsoundboard.R;

/**
 * Created by Oclemmy on 5/10/2016 for ProgrammingWizards Channel and http://www.Camposha.com.
 */
public class erstesFragment extends Fragment{


    GridView myGridView;
    public String[] items1 ={"alter schwede","Alter finne","was was was","ach schön","Du alte kacksau","Beatbox","Achjaa 1","Achjaa 2","Warum hast du eine Maske auf?"
            ,"boah 1","boah 2","Das Kackhuhn","Das ist doch wohl..."
            ,"Das ist ja unverschämt","das ist nicht wahr 1","das ist nicht wahr 2"
            ,"Das klappt ja super","eh","eh was","wie gemein","Engels-\nstimme","Englisch skills over 9000"
            ,"Freunde suche","Evil chicken","Pfui 1","Pfui 2","Gehirn-\naussetzer","Feierlaune","Gesangs-\neinlage 1"
            ,"Gesangs-\neinlage 2","Gesangs-\neinlage 3","was?","Miau","Halt die Fresse","hör auf","huaa","huch 1","huch 2","huiii","Ich bin noch ganz klein","ja geile scheiße","jaa"
            ,"Jo","kann man machen","Ihre Frau hat krebs","Komisches Geräusch 1","Komisches Geräusch 2","Komisches Geräusch 3","Komisches Geräusch 4","Komisches Geräusch 5","Komisches Geräusch 6","Komisches Geräusch 7"
            ,"Kuh 1","Kuh 2","Kuh 3","Definition von Kunstraum","Ladescreen 1","Ladescreen 2","Ladescreen 3","Ladescreen 4","Ladescreen 5","Ladescreen 6","Ladescreen 7","Ladescreen 8","Ladescreen 9"
            ,"Ledersofa aus Plastik","Mobbing spiel","Nachbar 1","Nachbar 2","Nachbar 3","Neiin 1","Neiin 2","Neiin 3","Neiin 4","Nein Nein Nein nein","niemals","ok","oke","oh man","Omi?","Omi bist dus?","Geschäfts-\nidee"
            ,"Der Pissnapf","Plastik-\nfliesen","Qualität","Dunkel wie im Rattenarsch","Räusperer","Rindenmulch","Die Scheere","wueah","schlipper","Schnauze!","Der Schwimmer","Soo 1"
            ,"soo 2","Spieglein Spieglein...","Sprachlos 1","Sprachlos 2","Stöhnen 1","Stöhnen 2","Stöhnen + Neiin","Das Treppenhaus","Tupperparty","und ähm 1","und ähm 2","Nur ein husten"
            ,"Wie geil ist das denn 1","Wie geil ist das denn 2"};

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.erstes_fragment,container,false);




        myGridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        myGridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), items1));

        return rootView;
    }




    public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private String[] items;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CustomGridAdapter(Context c, String[] items) {
            this.context = c;
            this.items = items;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            }
            Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setText(items[position]);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
                        ((MainActivity) context).itemClicked1(position);
                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }


    }
}
```

And my fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.aaron.waller.tanzverbotsoundboard.MainActivity">


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:columnWidth="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` does not support column spanning. You have to use `TableLayout` and `GridLayout` instead.

Comment: @TheUseraccawd Is it useful ?